# Is it possible to use store_result() and bind_result() with PHP PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

My question is fairly straightforward: Is it possible to use `store_result()` and `bind_result()` with PHP PDO?

Here is some example code I came across:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) { 
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); // Bind "$email" to parameter.
  $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt); // get variables from result.
  $stmt->fetch();
```

I have seen these used in the context of `mysqli`, but not with PHP PDO.  `store_result()` and `bind_result()` are referenced in mysqli on www.php.net.  I'm curious if they are valid, or if there are comparable methods.

Edit: Obviously there is some translation between the two methods. My assumption is that  `store_result` and `bind_result()` are similar to PDO's `fetch()` commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point is, **there is absolutely no point in using neither store_result() nor bind_result() with PDO**.
Just get your data and use it anywhere you wish. That's the very point of PDO.

```
$sql  = "SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($email));
$row  = $stmt->fetch();
```

Now you have your userdata in `$row` array.

Storing resulting row in separate variables is *very* seldom practice nowadays. But if you prefer such ancient way of dealing with data, you could add

```
extract($row);
```

to the above code to get your global variables.

The main problem with mysqli-way is that it is extremely hard to use it with whatever level of abstraction.

In the real life we *never* call for database in the *global scope*, but rather in a function like this

```
function getUserData() {
    // getting data
    return $array;
}
```

and for some reason this simple yet mostly used code become extremely difficult with mysqli! 
In the real life we don't need separate variables but rather single array to be returned. But with mysqli we need to get these variables first, then put them in array and only then return them. Just crazy!

Comment: That's a good point. I found that odd, since I've exclusively used PDO. It seemed like more steps than what I have implemented in the past.

Comment: Confused. First you emphasize that there is no point in it and then you immediatly suggest to use neither store_result nor bind_result

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `store_result` and `bind_result`; you can use the language construct [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). An example usage shall be:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
    FROM members 
    WHERE email = ? 
    LIMIT 1")
$stmt->bindValue( 1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
list($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt) = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_NUM );
```

The `PDO::FETCH_NUM` is used because:

> **`list()`** only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical
>   indices start at 0.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and I have recently used in my project.

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM member WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) 
{
    $stmt->bindparam(1, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) 
{
    echo"user exist";
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: `It is possible`.... except this code doesn't demonstrate the use of bind_result or store_result. It only uses bindparam, which has a different purpose. Also there's logical flaw in the code because if `$stmt` is false then `if ($stmt->rowCount()` will break. This answer makes no sense and doesn't answer the question.