# Why bind rsults in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

That is, assuming all data to ever enter the database is properly bound or is inserted directly from the script.  I get that preparing and binding data going in is very important for security -- but after this, why bind results?  Wouldn't it just be easier to stmt->get_result to get a result set and then have access to fetch assoc and the like?  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer by @YourCommonSense http://stackoverflow.com/a/16910282/1003917

Comment: It may simplify a few code structures. Normal looping over the result sets is usually simpler to understand however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing nothing.

Since stmt->get_result got introduced into API, it would be easier to use this method to get a result set