# while php and jquery - jquery not working if php has a while?

Tags: php, jquery

I don't know what is happening, but if I **haven't** any row in my php while to show jquery click will not work.

If I have one or more rows in WHILE jquery works.
If I remove the while part of php, it works.

php:

```
$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("select id, user from posts limit 10");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $user);

$i=0;
while($stmt->fetch()) { //if nothing to show JQUERY will not work
 $i=$i+1;
 show_p($id, $user);
}

$stmt->close();
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".changesize").click(function(e){
 alert("ok");
});
});
```

what is the problem with while and jquery? any ideas?

**EDIT-----------------------**
my temporary solution:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$num = $stmt->num_rows; //NUM ROWS

if($num>0){ //if more than 0 rows. call while

    $i=0;
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
...
```

Comment: What does `show_p()` do? - But PHP and JS / jQuery are two different languages and php will be parsed first before the js/jQuery, so if something isn't working it isn't because of the loop, but because of the output.

Comment: strange because if I remove `show_p()` the click still not working... but if I remove the while it is ok... @Epodax

Comment: @RickJoe : Please provide the code of show_p(id, user) function

Comment: @AliKhanusiya it is a simple function just to echo the id and user: `function show_p($id,$user){ echo"$id $user"; }`

Comment: Where does the element with the class attribute of `changesize` appear within your html?

Comment: @che-azeh it is before `</body>`

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is why the event doesn't execute on `.changesize` and how that's related to your PHP while loop. Do those two elements have any relationship?

Comment: @che-azeh nothing ;/ it is all here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the main cause of your problem, but here's a problem: you cannot use `bind_results()` with PHP Data Objects. There is no point in using it in the first place as PDO's functions handle all that hassle.

I'm concerned about the method because you pass the same variables to it which you pass to the `show_p()` function in the while loop; and your problem apparently comes from the `show_p()` function.

Undo that line with `bind_results()` and run your query again.

Comment: oh, it is mysqli not PDO... what should I use instead of `bind_result`?

Comment: Just take off the line containing `bind_result`. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908589/is-it-possible-to-use-store-result-and-bind-result-with-php-pdo

Comment: I will try to take the line off and tell you what happens! thank you