# What is the proper way to bind to different values in PDO equal to mysqli?

Tags: php, pdo

I have been converting a small login script i did to PDO trying to give it a try.

Code mysqli

```
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);

        if ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $is_valid = true;
        } else {
            $is_valid = false;
            self::logout();
        }
```

I changed to PDO

```
        $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $is_valid = true;
        } else {

            $is_valid = false;
            self::logout();
        }
```

in mysqli i was able to bind and store $id and $name but read those were not available in PDO

```
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
```

Comment: One thing though - in `mysqli` when you `bind_param` the variables do not need exist at that stage but in `PDO` there should be a variable in existence first - the value can be changed later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no equivalent of `bind_result` in PDO because you don't really need it. Just read the data from the row:

```
if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row["id"];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row["name"];
    $is_valid = true;
}
```

You also don't need the `$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);` line because there is no `:name` input parameter in your SQL.

More examples are available [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and elsewhere.

See also [Is it possible to use store_result() and bind_result() with PHP PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908589/is-it-possible-to-use-store-result-and-bind-result-with-php-pdo) for more useful background info.

Comment: There is an equivalent function. It's called `bindColumn()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php

Comment: @Dharman yes, although since you have to enumerate every column with a separate function call, it's substantially more verbose than using bind_result(). It's a similar concept, but because it only deals with one column at a time, it's arguably not functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent method is called [`bindColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php). You can bind a variable to one column in the result set.

```
/* Bind by column number */
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $id);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $name);

while ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
    print $name . "\t" . $id. "\n";
}
```

However, I would recommend writing simpler code. PDO is designed to be easier to use.

If you want to make the code simpler, use arrays. The method [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns an array with the current row. They are better when you need to fetch more than one column from the result. If you only need to fetch one column, use [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $name,
]);

if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $is_valid = true;
} else {
    $is_valid = false;
    self::logout();
}
```